# How to write multiple vectors to multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have 2 vectors of ints:

```
vector<int> even = {2, 4, 6, 8};
vector<int> odd = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
```

I am trying to pass these vectors into a 2d array so that they end up looking like this:

```
array[2][5] = {2, 4, 6, 8,
               1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
```

Writing a function to do this but I cant get it to work, this is the code so far:

```
void copy(vector<int> even, vector<int> odd,int arr[][COLMAX]){
    int vectors = 2;
    for(int row = 0; row < vectors; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < even.size(); col++){
            arr[row][col] = even[col];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Edit: Added function code

Comment: It's possible, yes. Just not that way. You can use [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to do this.

Comment: You need to 1) declare your new "container" (e.g. 2-day array), and then 2) copy.  There are several ways to access your std::vector: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-copy-vector-c/.  Personally, I'd just do an element-by-element copy in a "for()" loop.

Comment: Just note: Using `std::array<std::array<int,5>,2>` would also make it easier, while keeping the same underlying data structure.

Comment: You haven't compiled your code; there is no definition for `i`. You don't need outer `for` loop, as you know that `even` goes into row `0`, and `odd` - into `1`. You can't blindly loop up to the size of `even`, as `odd` might be shorter.

Comment: sorry, I added the right code... I had posted something else, not the actual function I was able to compile. Also, @VladFeinsteinb thanks, I'll remove outer for loop... I thought I had to nest for loops everytime I wrote/read to/from 2d array.

Comment: Well, now you are copying the content of `even` into both rows of your array. Anyway, the big question is: WHY?

Comment: @VladFeinstein because I'm struggling to understand how to read/write 2d arrays I guess... T__T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
void copy(vector<int> even, vector<int> odd,int arr[][COLMAX]){
    for(int col = 0; col < even.size(); col++){
        arr[0][col] = even[col];
    }
    for(int col = 0; col < odd.size(); col++){
        arr[1][col] = odd[col];
    }
```

}

Comment: @avalost_ you are welcome. The point I and other people here are making: why do you need that array if you already have a nice and safe vectors?

Comment: Indeed!  Simple and effective.  However, the size of `even` and `odd` could be larger than `COLMAX`, in which case your code would be UB.  And you assume that either arr is already initialised or no vector has less than COLMAX elements ;-)

Comment: @Christophe - agree; I only look at it as an exercise in addressing 2D array elements.

Answer (score 1):

### Why go for arrays if you can use vectors?

If you can use a 2D vector instead of a 2D array,  you'd have much more flexibility.  And it'll be very simple:

```
vector<int> even = {2, 4, 6, 8};
vector<int> odd = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
vector<vector<int>> v {even,odd};   // that's sufficient !! 

for (auto &r: v) {    // and this is only the printing of the results
    std::copy(r.cbegin(), r.cend(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
    cout <<endl; 
}
```

### If you must really use raw arrays...

Now if you really want to use fixed size 2D arrays,  you can update your function:

```
const size_t COLMAX=10;  
void mycopy(vector<int> even, vector<int> odd,int arr[][COLMAX]){
    vector<const vector<int> *>v ={&even,&odd}; 
    for(int row=0;  row<v.size(); row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col <COLMAX; col++){
            arr[row][col] = (col < v[row]->size() ?  (*v[row])[col]:0);
        }
    }
}
```

It uses a pointer to the vectors to avoid repeating several time the same code for the different vectors.  Moreover,  you could easily make it work for 3 or 4 vecotrs (and with a little imagination you could eaily adapt it for a variable number of arguments).

You can then use it as planned:

```
int myarr[2][COLMAX];
mycopy (even, odd, myarr); 
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    std::copy (myarr[i], myarr[i]+COLMAX, ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
    cout <<endl; 
}
```

The problem is that you do not keep track of the number of elements that are really in each line,  so you'd have either al lot of truncated lines,  or lines with a lot of trailing zeroes.

Comment: I was restricted to using a 2d array on this one but I'll keep your suggestion in mind, thanks!!

Comment: @avalost_ ok,  I edited to provide a more basic alternative.  Of course,  if you're not allowed to use alorigthm library,  just replace the std::copy with a loop